# Can I symlink /data?

Tags: nexus-one, internal-storage

I have a rooted Google/HTC Nexus One running Android 4.0, Cyanogenmod, and MIUI. These mods were done by the previous owner.

Considering that the amount of internal storage my phone has is really tiny, I'm always looking for ways to free up space. My current idea is to symlink either all or part of `/data` to somewhere on the SD card where I have lots of free space.

My question is, would this cause any problems? I've got a lot of Linux experience, but I'm an Android newbie. The filesystem seems to be a bit different from what I'm used to in the Linux world.

Also, are there any pitfalls I should be aware of, such as certain data that must be available before the SD card is mounted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use data2sd instead of [creating the symlink manually from the terminal](http://morganbye.net/blog/2012/03/moving-apps-from-the-android-phone-memory-to-sd-card-htc-desire/).
Usually sd cards are formatted with FAT32, data2sd creates an EXT2 embedded partition instead...

[more detailed explanation here](http://www.modaco.com/topic/331205-guide-how-to-get-more-free-space-for-your-apps/).

Comment: The first link is broken.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can do that. Scripts like data2sd do exactly that.

Comment: As in my edit above, are there any pitfalls I should be aware of, such as certain things that must not be moved to the SD card?

Comment: @ScottSeverance I would assume it would be the same behavior as if you installed an app to the SD card: don't do it for widgets or apps that typically run on start/in the background. Those apps/widgets have issues when installed to the SD card.