# How can I get rid of the low disk space notification?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, notifications, internal-storage, insufficient-memory

The low disk space notification frequently comes up. I can't get rid of it; the clear button doesn't clear it, and neither does tapping it. It's just taking up space. How can I get rid of it?

I've got 20 MB of free space on my phone, which isn't a lot, but it's sufficient. I already know how much space is available, so a constant reminder serves no purpose, as there's nothing I'm willing to delete to free up space.

This is a Google/HTC Nexus One running Android 4.0. (Quite an old phone to be running ICS, but it was like that when I aquired it secondhand.)

**Edits in response to the comments and answers:**

- I've already moved all possible apps to the SD card, and even a few that weren't *supposed* to be moved there. Unfortunately, Android insists on keeping some stuff on the phone, even when the apps are moved off. As a Linux user, I can't understand this. By a combination of choosing the `$PATH` well and manipulating mount points and symlinks appropriately, I can't see why it should make *any* difference to the system where the app is installed.
- I've already cleared the cache. There's not much there, since I've been aggressive in my cache management. I've even cleared out several apps' data.
- I haven't yet gotten around to moving my data to the SD card, as [I asked about here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23830/can-i-symlink-data). I think it'll only amount to a few MB of savings, though.

Comment: Can you move apps to the SD Card? That may be your best bet. There are a few other suggestions in my [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/2315/15) to a similar question.

Comment: Just as an aside, Android won't let you keep some stuff on the external SD because (1) it's removable and (2) it's FAT32 and so file permissions are an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enormously annoying, isn't it?  There's no way to suppress it on an unmodified system that I know of, but you *can* at least free up more internal disk space by emptying system and app caches using an app like [SD Maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm) or by going into the application management section (`Settings->Applications->Manage Applications->All`, then click on an app name) and manually clearing out app data for hogs like Google Maps and the like using the `Clear cache` button (note: don't clear the app **data**! just the **cache**).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added additional details to my question, but they probably won't change your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Right, I have the solution. Swipe down to get notifications, then hold down on the screen where it says 'insufficient storage'. A little window will appear saying 'app info'. Press that and it will take you to settings of your android system. There is a ticked box saying 'show notifications'
Untick that box and the problem is solved.
( the box can be ticked again afterwards, so you can receive other notifications, but the problem should not reoccur).
(as of 2020, you can no longer uncheck that box)

Answer (score 3):

Run these commands from `adb shell` or a root terminal (the second may not work on later versions of Android):

```
settings put secure sys_storage_threshold_percentage 5
settings put gservices sys_storage_threshold_percentage 5
```

The default threshold is 10%, so you can decrease it to 5% or possibly even lower.